# I need to upload file on server by PopUp window by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    <td>File:</td>
    <input type="file" name="File" id="File" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
    <td align="right" valign="middle">
         <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" />
    </td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreviewImage() {
             var oFReader = new FileReader();
             oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("File").files[0]);

             oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                 document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
             };
        };
    </script>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Upload" /></td> 
}
```

Comment: I can't see the actual question here, what was the issue?

Comment: i need to upload the image but i am facing problem in when above code is inserted in view(MVC 4) then create list also submitted